# pipelineJob: is this part of the job-dsl plugin or Pipeline: Job?

Tags: jenkins, plugins

Looking at:

https://jenkinsci.github.io/job-dsl-plugin/#path/pipelineJob

the URL path says it's part of the `job-dsl-plugin` but the green button on the right says it requires `Pipeline: Job` which is here: https://plugins.jenkins.io/workflow-job/

I'm confused which plugin it's part of.

Comment: Hello. You are reading job dsl docs regarding creation of pipeline job in dsl. To use this possibilities you need to install "Pipeline: Job" plugin (in old way it is called workflow job) in your jenkins controller.

Comment: Checking out https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-job-plugin I don't see any code for `pipelineJob`.

Comment: It means you need to find out what job dsl plugin is first.